# How to deserialize json into hashmap within object?

Tags: java, json, serialization, gson

I'm new to gson. I want to deserialize json attributes into hashmaps within java object, and there are bunch of such jsons to be deser'ed into bunch of objects. 
for example, the jsons comes as an array; looks like,

```
[
{"type":"type1","name":"name1","attr1":123},
{"type":"type1","name":"name1","attr2":123},
{"type":"type1","name":"name1","attr3":123},
{"type":"type1","name":"name1","attr1":123},
{"type":"type1","name":"name1","attr2":123},
{"type":"type1","name":"name1","attr3":123}
]
```

note that the jsons have some attribute names common (type and name), and some attribute names different (attr1, attr2, attr3, etc)

I want to deserialize this attributes in json into the Map inside the java object,

```
public class Object {

   Map<String, Integer> props_ = new HashMap<>();

   public boolean has(String prop) {
       return props_.containsKey(prop);
   }

   public Integer get(String prop) {
       return props_.get(prop);
   }

   public void set(String prop, Integer value) {
       props_.put(prop, value);
   }
 }
```

so the props_ map should have type, name, and attr1 for 1st json, and
type, name, and attr2 for 2nd json, etc

Comment: You can write a custom deserializer.

Comment: @AlexisC. any hint on how to write custom deser.?

Comment: I could show you but I'm unclear what should be the expected output for your input. Should `props` contain all the third key-value pairs of each object in the array? And where is stored type and name key-value pairs? Because looking at the type of your map you cannot store them into it.